# FireFox 4 padding wrong in a horizontal CSS Menu

Tags: css, firefox, menu, padding

I have a horizontal CSS menu at this page:

http://72.47.251.205/ak9

In Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer 8 it renders perfectly. In FireFox 4, each `<li>` is just slightly too narrow, leaving a gap between the last two items.

Here's a quick example of the HTML:

```
<ul id="top-nav">
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
 <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
#top-nav {
 position: relative;
}

#top-nav li {
 float: left;
 height: 46px;
 line-height: 46px;
 width: auto;
}

#top-nav li.last-item {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

#top-nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 38px;
}
```

I tried using the `-moz-box-sizing` CSS attribute on the `body` tag, but to no avail.

Thanks to anyone who has any ideas.

### UPDATE

It was brought to my attention that FF 4 in Windows renders this appropriately, but IE 9 does not. It appears that this is a cross-platform as well as cross-browser inconsistency. It's really starting to concern me.

Also, I used absolute positioning on the last item to ensure that it stays flush right with the .wrapper div that keeps everything centered. That way, browser inconsistencies in rendering box-width would never be able to "break" the menu by forcing the last item to the second line, something way worse than what's going on now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got it right mate? I have looked the same in IE8, FF 4.0 and FF 4.0.1, and they look right. However in IE9, the problem you describe happens as there is a gap between the last two items, Media and Blog!

[IE9](http://i54.tinypic.com/2r2rfc4.jpg)

[FF 4.0.1](http://i55.tinypic.com/690znp.jpg)

The reason the gap is there because you have set position: absolute on the last list item with offset properties set at top: 0; right:0; - If you remove this, the gap will be gone.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. This may be a Mac/Windows issue. I'm looking at it in FF 4 on a Mac, and IE8 in Windows XP. I'll look at it in FF on WXP and see what happens. As to the position:absolute, I set it that way to ensure that the last item is flush right to the page design without the fear of it breaking the line because of how a particular browser might render <li> padding.

Comment: You could remove any default li padding given by browsers by including li {padding: 0; margin: 0;} in your CSS reset, if you have one. If you dont have CSS reset just include the above rule directly in you stylesheet by adding ul.menu>li {padding: 0; margin: 0;}. Next remove the relative position from the ul.menu and remove absolute position from the last li item. Next give your ul.menu a width of 960px, the same as the div.wrapper. Next give text-align: center to the ul.menu. Now you will have a centered navigation across all browsers. Tested on IE 9, FF 4.0.1, GG 11, AF 5.0.5 and Operal 11.

Comment: The problem with that is that if any `<li>` is even slightly incorrectly rendered, it will force the last item to the next line, which breaks the design. The position:absolute prevents this from happening, in case the inconsistent rendering adds or subtracts a few pixels. In a situation like this one, where the width of each `<li>` has to be determine by its content, this is the only way of which I'm aware to prevent this behavior. It also means that the last `<li>` might not line up flush with the right side of the .wrapper.